# Sonarlint Eclipse StackOverflowError

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarlint

`SonarLint` for Eclipse crashes with the following scenario:

Create a couple of files in the same package:

1. Menu.java

   ```
   package com.leokom.sonarlint.stackoverflowerror;

   public interface Menu {

   }
   ```
2. SomeClass.java

   ```
   package com.leokom.sonarlint.stackoverflowerror;

   public class SomeClass {
       enum Menu implements Menu {
       }
   }
   ```

When SonarLint analyzes the SomeClass.java, a crash occurs with Eclipse suggesting to exit:

Error shown:

```
An internal error occurred during: "SonarLint analysis of file /GoodJob/src/main/java/com/leokom/sonarlint/stackoverflowerror/SomeClass.java". java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

SonarLint Console:

```
SonarLint analysis of file /GoodJob/src/main/java/com/leokom/sonarlint/stackoverflowerror/SomeClass.java...
```

What should I do with this use case? How can I solve it?

Comment: Just for the record: shadowing names like naming an Enum after an interface it implements ... that is a really bad idea. Don't do that.

Comment: Edited question to be clear as to what is being asked. @GhostCat , RaYell , RP- , Sam Dufel , Adam Kipnis : please reconsider the 'put on hold status' placed on this question. Thanks you for your time.

Comment: I think there is no real answer to this. As others have said - it is more like you discovered a bug - then writing a bug report is your first choice. Beyond that, I would rethink if you really want to name that enum `Menu` to then implement an interface named `Menu` . Names should communicate intent. That is hard when you use the same name repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed the described use case in the question and encountered the same bug as the OP (also tried to reproduce this in IntelliJ, but apparently this is an Eclipse only issue).

I opened a bug for the SonnarSource team which can be seen [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!topic/sonarlint/-AVbqO05QDA).

I will update the answer based on the answers I get from SonarSource.

Followup: The SonarSource team has opened the [SLE-272 JIRA issue](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLE-272) about this problem. It has been reported by [Julian Henry](https://stackexchange.com/users/255011). It should be resolved in version 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

I think your original code causes an infinite recursion. Try changing your code to

```
package com.leokom.sonarlint.stackoverflowerror;
public class SomeClass {
    enum Menu implements com.leokom.sonarlint.stackoverflowerror.Menu {
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, it's a cyclic reference, but the tool should print an error message instead of crashing.

Comment: Confirmed @KlitosKyriacou's comment via the Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEs. The proposed solution here masks the bug in SonarLint.